# Bulk duplicate records in table and reinsert in same table updating only 2 columns (maintaining revision for each edit)

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I have a scenario where I have to maintain revision of whole data in the postgresql table. Initially the revision column start from 0 and is_latest_revision column will be true. There are around 120,000 records in the table and each time even if single record is updated/newly added/deleted whole table data need to be duplicated and revision column will be incremented to next value(1) and the new 120,000 records will have is_latest_revision as true. For old records revision value remains 0 but is_latest_revision will be false.

Is there a efficient way to do this in java spring boot?

I was thinking about findAll() and saveAll() methods from Jpa, but that would take time.

Comment: What did you try to solve the problem, first provide your solution or at least some presumptions, some codes might be useful.